# getting many messages of a Table change from data gridview in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, autocomplete, sqldatareader

i made this coding actually find in stuckoverflow :) and i re made it according to my application and changed connection string and tabe name as well as raw name, it is all correct, no more errors before compiling when i have entered have value to text box i am getting an error at "con.open();" after the connection string plz help me my error message is "Instance failure."
my coding is `

```
 private void textBox_ItemId_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AutoCompleteStringCollection namesCollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SAROTH-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=noorsons;Integrated Security=True");
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand cmnd = connection.CreateCommand();
        cmnd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmnd.CommandText = "SELECT itemcode FROM Invoice_New_Details";
        SqlDataReader dReader;
        dReader = cmnd.ExecuteReader();

        if (dReader.Read())
        {
            while (dReader.Read())
                namesCollection.Add(dReader["english"].ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Data not found");
        }
        dReader.Close();

        textBox_ItemId.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
        textBox_ItemId.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
        textBox_ItemId.AutoCompleteCustomSource = namesCollection;
        }`
```

Comment: doesn't look like asp.net. You should remove the `asp.net` tag and add `winforms` tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have marked your connection string with '@', you don't need to have a double slash for Data Source.

```
Data Source=SAROTH-PC\SQLEXPRESS
```

Comment: yes Poornima That error is solved but help me i got another error access violation in my Program.cs error message is "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt." wot to do

Comment: Can you provide some more details? Which line of code is causing the error?

Comment: Application.Run(new Stock_Entry()); this lie and error is coming in program.cs

Comment: ok done it is solved, i changed in text box properties modifiers as public cheers tnx a ton :D :D